# How to keep Prolog from going back and forth between the same two steps forever?

Tags: prolog, towers-of-hanoi

Behold the following "solution" to the Towers of Hanoi problem:

```
f([],[],_).

f([A|As],[],C) :- f(As,[A],C).
f([A|As],B,[]) :- f(As,B,[A]).

f([],[B|Bs],C) :- f([B],Bs,C).
f(A,[B|Bs],[]) :- f(A,Bs,[B]).

f([],B,[C|Cs]) :- f([C],B,Cs).
f(A,[],[C|Cs]) :- f(A,[C],Cs).

f([A|As],[B|Bs],C) :- A < B, f(As,[A,B|Bs],C).
f([A|As],B,[C|Cs]) :- A < C, f(As,B,[A,C|Cs]).

f([A|As],[B|Bs],C) :- B < A, f([B,A|As],Bs,C).
f(A,[B|Bs],[C|Cs]) :- B < C, f(A,Bs,[B,C|Cs]).

f([A|As],B,[C|Cs]) :- C < A, f([C,A|As],B,Cs).
f(A,[B|Bs],[C|Cs]) :- C < B, f(A,[C,B|Bs],Cs).
```

But this will never finish as Prolog is getting stuck at moving disk 1 back and forth between rod A and B ad infinitum:

```
[trace]  ?- f([1,2,3],[],[]).
   Call: (10) f([1, 2, 3], [], []) ? creep
   Call: (11) f([2, 3], [1], []) ? creep
   Call: (12) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (13) 3<1 ? creep
   Fail: (13) 3<1 ? creep
   Redo: (12) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (13) 3<2 ? creep
   Fail: (13) 3<2 ? creep
   Redo: (12) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (13) 1<3 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 1<3 ? creep
   Call: (13) f([1, 3], [], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (14) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (15) 3<1 ? creep
   Fail: (15) 3<1 ? creep
   Redo: (14) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (15) 3<2 ? creep
   Fail: (15) 3<2 ? creep
   Redo: (14) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (15) 1<3 ? creep
   Exit: (15) 1<3 ? creep
   Call: (15) f([1, 3], [], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (16) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (17) 3<1 ? creep
   Fail: (17) 3<1 ? creep
   Redo: (16) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (17) 3<2 ? creep
   Fail: (17) 3<2 ? creep
   Redo: (16) f([3], [1], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (17) 1<3 ? creep
   Exit: (17) 1<3 ? creep
   Call: (17) f([1, 3], [], [2]) ? creep
   Call: (18) f([3], [1], [2]) ? 
   [...]
```

I'm generally aware of `cut`s being used in similar situations. But where would you place a cut here if that is required or indicated?

How to make this program finish without having to rearrange it based on specifics of the backtrack trace? Because I assume this would be an option here but this is of course a toy example.

Comment: That is the usual "path" problem - add a safeguard to not revisit the same "state", i.e. the same layout of disks - see the `\+ member` at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53478218/

Comment: Why am I even bothering with Prolog then? That's like buying a car but you have to pull it.

Comment: I think a better metaphor is that you've bought a Ferrari but keep it in 5th gear :-) Languages don't fix your broken code for you. They let you implement your clever algorithm.

Comment: how about you just tell me then what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Simply take a look at already-existing decent solutions, just a quick googling away, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39987150/

Comment: The solution you link to is of procedural/imperative nature and basically equivalent to what you would do in Python or C if you choose recursion over iteration. This is why I do not agree that this is a good solution in context of Prolog where the approach should be declarative: you describe the problem and have Prolog solve it. Which is what my code is attempting. After all that's why one would be motivated to use Prolog. There is no point in using Prolog if you fall back to a procedural/imperative programming paradigm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39987150/ is a *declarative* solution - each line in it is a "pure" ( https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/purity ) declarative constraint. See also https://gist.github.com/pragdave/0207669683ab18b28caa8e5732ed1f67

Comment: thanks @brebs, especially for the github link. that looks very interesting.

Comment: You are bothering with Prolog because it is a nice programming language in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to /u/brebs something like this would be the most straightforward adaption of my code, keeping track of and avoiding past states. This does not just look ugly it is - if I dare to say - downright unmaintainable. Hence I hope some Prolog Yedi is taking notice of my plight and enlightens me as how to do it right.

```
f([],[],_,P,P).

f([A|As],[],C,P,P_) :- 
    \+ member([As,[A],C],P), 
    f(As,[A],C,[[As,[A],C]|P],P_).
f([A|As],B,[],P,P_) :- 
    \+ member([As,B,[A]],P), 
    f(As,B,[A],[[As,B,[A]]|P],P_).

f([],[B|Bs],C,P,P_) :- 
    \+ member([[B],Bs,C],P), 
    f([B],Bs,C,[[[B],Bs,C]|P],P_).
f(A,[B|Bs],[],P,P_) :- 
    \+ member([A,Bs,[B]],P), 
    f(A,Bs,[B],[[A,Bs,[B]]|P],P_).

f([],B,[C|Cs],P,P_) :- 
    \+ member([[C],B,Cs],P), 
    f([C],B,Cs,[[[C],B,Cs]|P],P_).
f(A,[],[C|Cs],P,P_) :- 
    \+ member([A,[C],Cs],P), 
    f(A,[C],Cs,[[A,[C],Cs]|P],P_).

f([A|As],[B|Bs],C,P,P_) :- A < B, 
    \+ member([As,[A,B|Bs],C],P), 
    f(As,[A,B|Bs],C,[[As,[A,B|Bs],C]|P],P_).
f([A|As],B,[C|Cs],P,P_) :- A < C, 
    \+ member([As,B,[A,C|Cs]],P), 
    f(As,B,[A,C|Cs],[[As,B,[A,C|Cs]]|P],P_).

f([A|As],[B|Bs],C,P,P_) :- B < A, 
    \+ member([[B,A|As],Bs,C],P), 
    f([B,A|As],Bs,C,[[[B,A|As],Bs,C]|P],P_).
f(A,[B|Bs],[C|Cs],P,P_) :- B < C, 
    \+ member([A,Bs,[B,C|Cs]],P), 
    f(A,Bs,[B,C|Cs],[[A,Bs,[B,C|Cs]]|P],P_).

f([A|As],B,[C|Cs],P,P_) :- C < A, 
    \+ member([[C,A|As],B,Cs],P), 
    f([C,A|As],B,Cs,[[[C,A|As],B,Cs]|P],P_).
f(A,[B|Bs],[C|Cs],P,P_) :- C < B, 
    \+ member([A,[C,B|Bs],Cs],P), 
    f(A,[C,B|Bs],Cs,[[A,[C,B|Bs],Cs]|P],P_).
```

At least it terminates with a solution.

```
?- f([1,2,3],[],[],[[[1,2,3],[],[]]],P), reverse(P,P_), write(P_).

[[[1,2,3],[],[]],[[2,3],[1],[]],[[3],[1],[2]],[[1,3],[],[2]],
 [[1,3],[2],[]],[[3],[2],[1]],[[3],[1,2],[]],[[],[1,2],[3]],
 [[1],[2],[3]],[[],[2],[1,3]],[[2],[],[1,3]],[[2],[1],[3]],
 [[],[1],[2,3]],[[1],[],[2,3]],[[],[],[1,2,3]]]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37501585/ for some explanation of the possible code refinement.

Answer (score 2):

For beginners, clpfd is debatable to include (and is also overkill for this simple task), so here's the [Peano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+successor-arithmetics) equivalent of [lurker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37501585/):

```
% Ending state
move(0, _, _, _) --> [].
% "s" for "successor"
move(s(N), P1, P2, P3) -->
    move(N, P1, P3, P2),
    [P1-to-P2],
    move(N, P3, P2, P1).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- phrase(move(s(s(s(0))), left, center, right), Moves).
Moves = [left-to-center, left-to-right, center-to-right,
left-to-center, right-to-left, right-to-center, left-to-center].
```

This has fewer unwanted choicepoints, since `0` vs `s(N)` is covered by first-argument indexing.

`s(s(s(0)))` is 4 as Peano. [Here's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645668/) to convert.

`-->` is DCG notation, which in essence provides efficient and succinct list-handling.

Comment: this is actually also "just" the usual recursive solution (the one we discussed under the question) using imperative programming :/ still, interesting and food for thought, so +1 for that.

Comment: The code's elegance, for this simple problem, isn't a reason to recategorize Prolog away from a declarative language :-) Put another way - explain why you think *any* of those lines of code can't be considered declarative.

Comment: my guess is that the OP doesn't consider it "declarative" because it was the human programmer who had to come up with this nice and clever and succinct code, applying the recursive problem-solving paradigm. IOW this code is already a solution, it is not a statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You evidently want to define the search space by describing the legal moves and the final state, and let the search engine find its way to the solution on its own. But Prolog is a *depth-first* search engine, so it doesn't work here because, as coded, the search space has infinite depth, as you rightly note. The enumeration of attempted solution isn't "fair" since Prolog works in top-down left-to-right order which is what leads to it being "depth-first".

A general answer to this is to use some kind of diagonalization of streams of partial solutions that can deal with infinite depth as well as infinite branching, to get a "fair enumeration" of solutions.

Here though the branching, i.e. the number of legal moves from each legal position, is finite, so the simpler, breadth-first exploration is sufficient.

So instead of coding the moves one by one, code up just *one* transition rule that turns *a position* into a *list* of *all* valid *"next"* positions. Then it's easy to code the breadth-first search with that.

Just pop a position from an "agenda" list of positions to explore -- initially containing just one, starting position -- then turn that position to a list of its next positions, and *append* that list to the agenda, putting it at its end. This is what makes it breadth first, exploring the space level by level, so that the shortest path to the solution, if any, is found first.

Prepending it at the start of the agenda list would result in the depth-first search again. Mixing the two up in some clever ways would make the search be clever, in some strange and clever way. Like if you had some heuristics, you could put the *"better"* solutions first.

Instead of positions you can maintain the whole paths i.e. sequences of moves leading to each position, if needed.

You'll still have to code it all yourself, since Prolog is a depth-first, top-down left-to-right search engine. It's a programming language, it is not a declarative programming system that would analyze your code by itself, and find ways to get to the solution by itself, a system that would be aware of its own computation processes and capable of adjusting itself, switching from depth first to breadth first or to diagonalization, all on its own, as one example. Prolog doesn't do that.

Comment: very insightful - gonna take a while until I understand everything, though. thanks. ghc is infamous for large amount of flags altering details about the compilation. wouldn't something like a feature that adds some randomness to the graph traversal be useful here? also it seems plausible that it should be detectable if the search algo gets stuck. I believe sth-like-Prolog has a bright future. maybe with non symbolic machine learning under the hood.

Comment: what I am actually trying to do is program a freecell solver. and using above approach. it's deceptively easy to describe everything about how the cards can be moved around. but I got stuck at having to write 8x(8-1) predicates for the 8 cascades only. so I reduced it to towers of hanoi to ask how to achieve reusability - without using a macro ;) and then I got stuck at above code not finishing ... so my actual question was whether this can be rewritten using less predicates. but well ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick stab at a more elegant solution than the OP's:

```
start_state(N, st(L, [], [])) :-
    numlist(1, N, L).

end_state(st([], [], _)).

% Can move any disk to an empty tower
% Destination is first arg, for first-argument indexing
can_move([], [H|T], [H], T).
% Can move disk if smaller
can_move([E|R], [H|T], [H|[E|R]], T) :-
    E > H.

can_moves(E, E, _, []).
can_moves(State, EndState, Visited, [SrcT-DesT|Moves]) :-
    % Prepare NextState
    functor(NextState, st, 3),
    % Select action
    Towers = [1, 2, 3],
    select(SrcT, Towers, Towers0),
    select(DesT, Towers0, [OtherT]),
    arg(SrcT, State, SrcL),
    arg(DesT, State, DesL),
    can_move(DesL, SrcL, DesNext, SrcNext),
    % Assemble NextState
    arg(SrcT, NextState, SrcNext),
    arg(DesT, NextState, DesNext),
    % The unchanged tower
    arg(OtherT, State, Other),
    arg(OtherT, NextState, Other),
    % Prevent infinite loop
    \+ member(NextState, Visited),
    % Loop
    can_moves(NextState, EndState, [NextState|Visited], Moves).

moves(NumOfDisks, Moves) :-
    start_state(NumOfDisks, StartState),
    end_state(EndState),
    can_moves(StartState, EndState, [StartState], Moves).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- length(M, _), moves(3, M).
M = [1-3, 1-2, 3-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-3, 1-3] ;
...

?- length(M, _), moves(4, M).
M = [1-2, 1-3, 2-3, 1-2, 3-1, 3-2, 1-2, 1-3, 2-3, 2-1, 3-1, 2-3, 1-2, 1-3, 2-3] ;
...
```

This is using `length/2` to get the shortest list of moves *first*, as the easiest/laziest way - could instead implement breadth-first-search will a tiny bit of extra effort, as Will Ness mentioned.

Comment: [OP's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160743/849891) finds 1872 solutions with lengths `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]`, the shortest of which is  of 8 positions, i.e. 7 moves `[1-3, 1-2, 3-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-3, 1-3]`.

Comment: That is with 3 disks rather than 4 (keeping with 3 towers) - have added that example :-)